# Creating a list of dataset fields and form fields for easy updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a relatively complex dataset (numerous tables, some with multiple records) generated from reading in an XML file.  I need to connect said dataset fields to an ASP form.  At the moment I'm assigning them manually, like so in the pageload:

```
txt_first_init.Text = formData.ds.Tables["phrmHdrKey"].Rows[0]["first_init"].ToString();
txt_last_name.Text = formData.ds.Tables["phrmHdrKey"].Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString();
ddl_pregnancy_flag.SelectedValue = formData.ds.Tables["pPhrm"].Rows[0]["pregnancy_flag"].ToString();
```

And conversely when it's time to submit.

```
formData.ds.Tables["phrmHdrKey"].Rows[0]["first_init"] = txt_first_init.Text;
formData.ds.Tables["phrmHdrKey"].Rows[0]["last_name"] = txt_last_name.Text;
formData.ds.Tables["pPhrm"].Rows[0]["pregnancy_flag"] = ddl_pregnancy_flag.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I did some looking into binding the textboxes (and dropdownlists, and checkboxes, and and and...) directly, but it seemed to be too many formats to use.

So this works fine, but as the number of fields increases, those load and unload lists are going to get unwieldy.

Trying to come up with a way to make a future update or addition so said list neater.  I've gotten a very hand-wavy suggestion to place the two columns of names into a list, but unsure how to set such up, and how to load the items into a function that could evaluate and run the resulting commands.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

see here: [Dynamic Form Generation in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792278/dynamic-form-generation-in-asp-net)

looks like MS Dynamic Data is the answer.

Comment: Let me elaborate. I have a form with fields already created.  I have a series of simple statements (listed above) to load those fields with values, and to load any changed values from the fields.  They all run the format:

field.text = value.ToString()
value = field.text.ToString()

What I'd like is a more versatile to run those numerous calls, and not have to re-write each one twice, just slightly edited.

It's been suggested I could load the field and value info into a list, and just run them through a loop that would turn it into "(field item) = (value item).ToString()" or vice versa.