# User defined form creation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to create dynamic fields for form. Searched online and here and found [this design guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792278/dynamic-form-generation-in-asp-net) while it miss some of my requirements. I don't need exact code but general guideline.

**User** will have DropDownList with **Properties** he can add. Each **Property** divided into two parts. First part is for **User** to use for **SearchCombination** ( combination of **Properties**) and other part is for **Customer** to use.

ie. **User** chooses **Age** in DropDownList, this should produce **AgeFrom/AgeTo** DropdownLists on **SearchCombination** page and Day/Month/Year DropDownLists on **Customer** page.

How can i tackle this problem? Again i need only guideline and no real code unless you want to so please no suggestions "What have you tried", this is design question.

**The only solution i see it to follow solution above while SearchCombination and Costumer control groups will be UserControls at the same table**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny simple version, hope this guides you in the right direction

```
  if(DropDownList.SelectedValue == "age")
    {
       DropDownList listFromAge = new DropDownList();
       listFromAge.DataSource = myAgeDataSource;
       Controls.Add(listFromAge);

       DropDownList listToAge = new DropDownList();
       listToAge.DataSource = myAgeDataSource;
       Controls.Add(listToAge);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i'm looking for more maintainable solution than having 20 IFs over each page i need this.